# Vue CLI not processing JS files inside node_modules imported from Vue files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I'm using the Vue CLI and have my project building with modern mode. I'm noticing that any of the JS files I include from node_modules from Vue files are minified but let, const, and arrow functions are not being replaced. This is the case even in my legacy bundles. My own JS files are processed correctly. All my Vue files process fine.

Anyone know how I can get Babel to process included JS files and not just minify them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use Vue cli's `transpileDependencies` option. Just set it to an array of Regex to match your dependencies that need compiling.